# How to fix this phenomenon on my c3 line chart? missing dashed line

Tags: javascript, d3.js, linechart, c3.js

[Missing dashed line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7lHJ.png)

I can't get correctly dash line in my c3 chart when I use regions option.
please, let me know how can I fix this phenomenon. I couldn't get any information from anywhere about this kind of problem...
Here is my code

```
var chart = c3.generate({
data: {
  
    types: {
                    firstWeekData: 'bar',
                    secondWeekData: 'bar',
                    thirdWeekData: 'bar',
                    fourthWeekData: 'bar',
                    fifthWeekData: 'bar',
                    monthData: 'line',
                    year: 'line',
                    refLine: 'line'
            },
            regions: {
                    'year': [{'end': 11}]
            },
    columns: [
        
            ["firstWeekData", 7.627, 5.766, 8.302, 6.261, 7.592, 5.663, 8.978, 6.627, 9.961, 7.557, 7.366, 7.281],
            ["secondWeekData", 7.087, 8.138, 8.058, 5.726, 9.218, 7.265, 8.307, 6.821, 12.687, 7.693, 7.12, 8.987],
            ["thirdWeekData", 7.363, 8.122, 8.157, 6.123, 8.702, 7.85, 9.103, 0, 7.127, 7.24, 6.699, 8.451],
            ["fourthWeekData", 7.204, 8.414, 7.718, 7.846, 7.342, 10.356, 4.648, 9.153, 7.359, 0, 5.834, 9.735],
            ["fifthWeekData", 0, 0, 7.871, 0, 0, 7.535, 0, 8.597, 7.633, 0, 7.61, 7.729],
            ["monthData", 7.309, 7.636, 7.992, 6.397, 8.293, 8.03, 7.784, 8.332, 8.171, 7.537, 7.037, 8.545],
            ["year", 7.789, 7.789, 7.789, 7.789, 7.789, 7.789, 7.789, 7.789, 7.789, 7.789, 7.789, 7.789],
            ["refLine", 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9],
            
    ],
    
},
point: {
                r: function (d) {

                    // console.log('pointer d.id', d.id)
                    if (d.id === 'refLine' || d.id === 'year') return 0
                    return 5
                },
                show: true
},
bar: {
                width: 8,
                space: 0.1
},
axis: {
                x: {
                    type: 'category',
                    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
                }
},
line: {
  connectNull: true
}
            
});
```